# Node.js return result/error from mysql conn.query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, async-await, promise

I hope anyone can help me.
I tried to invoke the function `createProduct` and create a new dataset in my `MySQL` database.
But I want to return the error/result.

```
let sql = "INSERT INTO ZUTAT (ZUTATENNR, BEZEICHNUNG, EINHEIT, NETTOPREIS, BESTAND, LIEFERANT, KALORIEN, KOHLENHYDRATE, PROTEIN, Gelistet, Bild) VALUES ?";
let values = [
  [data.pNr, data.pName, data.pUnit, data.pPrice, data.pCount, '101', data.pKa, data.pKo, data.pPr, data.pListed, data.pImage]
];
let output;

con.query(sql, [values], function(err, result) {

  if (err) {
    console.log('Error: ' + err);
    returnBack(err);
  } else {
    console.log('Result: ' + result);
    returnBack(result);
  }
});

function returnBack(returnValue) {
  console.log('Return: ' + returnValue);
  output = returnValue;
}

l().then({
  function() {
    console.log('t: ' + output);
    return output;
  }
})
}
```

The problem is that the `return` statement executes before the `con.query` does.
I tried `async` but it doesn't works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: You are mixing synchron code with asynchron code execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if O want to return value from createProduct I would do smth like that:

```js
let createProduct = async function(data) {

  let sql = "...";
  let values = [...]

  return new Promise((res, rej)=>{
   con.query(sql, [values], function (err, result) {
     if (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
        rej(err);
     } else {
        console.log('Result: ' + result);
        res(result);
     }
  });
  }
}

// later in the code (inside async function)
let result = await createProduct(data);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: It works. I also changed that the error is returned as res so that the server doesn't always crash. Thanks very much!